# Calling session Bean deployed on jboss 5.x from client side

Tags: ejb-3.0, client-side, jboss5.x

I'm running JBoss 5.1 GA with JDK 1.6 on Linux and trying to call session bean(jar containing this session bean is deployed on jboss server), Now i want to call this session bean from client, but didnt work.

Java Code at client Side

```
public class CallingJbossSessionBeanFromClient {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    p.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
    p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://182.158.93.41:8080");
    Context context = new InitialContext(p);
    System.out.println("Successfully Lookup and going to call SessionBean Function deployed on JBoss-5.1.0 Server");
    SlsSessiongRemote remote=(SlsSessionRemote) context.lookup("SlsSessionBean/remote");
//SlsSessionBean/remote is RemoteBinding of session Bean
    System.out.println("Called");
}
}
```

where 'SlsSessionBean/remote' is remote binding of session bean deployed on jboss server.
@Stateless
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding="SlsSessionBean/remote")

but end up with following error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory]
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:657)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
at CallingJbossSessionBeanFromClient.main(CallingJbossSessionBeanFromClient.java:20)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:303)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:46)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:654)
... 4 more
```

After seeing above error i added jbossjmx-ant.jar in the classpath of 'CallingJbossSessionBeanFromClient' class and got following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/Logger
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.<clinit>(NamingContext.java:181)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory.getInitialContext(NamingContextFactory.java:55)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
at CallingJbossSessionBeanFromClient.main(CallingJbossSessionBeanFromClient.java:20)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logging.Logger
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:303)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
... 7 more
```

After seeing above error i added jboss-logging-spi.jar in the classpath of 'CallingJbossSessionBeanFromClient' class and got following error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: 182.158.93.41:8080 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to retrieve stub from server /182.158.93.41:8080 [Root exception is java.io.EOFException]]
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1763)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:693)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
at CallingJbossSessionBeanFromClient.main(CallingJbossSessionBeanFromClient.java:22)
       Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to retrieve stub from server /182.158.93.41:8080 [Root exception is java.io.EOFException]
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:327)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1734)
... 4 more
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2281)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2750)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:780)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:280)
at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:312)
... 5 more
```

Plz tell me, am i on the right way to call sesion bean from client java class?
I have spent hours looking for solution on Google. However I cannot seem to find anything that holds the hand..try to be more clear, i'm in lack of ideas in this problem, even it sounds like a classic 
Plz suggest solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to open the JMX-Console and click on the service=Naming to view the MBean view of the Naming service. Check if the port used is still 1099.....
Changed the URL to jnp://182.158.93.41:1299, the client could communicate with the EJB.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running over JBoss AS 5.x
Here is RMI based JNDI description.

RMI-Port: default -1099 / If dynamic port changed to ports-01 Then Port is 1199

Now, Remaining Things are OK, Modify code ass below

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
p.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://182.158.93.41:1199");
```

Another Point is case of accessing

SlsSessiongRemote remote=(SlsSessionRemote) context.lookup("SlsSessionBean/remote");
if - @Stateless(name="SlsSessionBean")

Then Remote JNDI- [SlsSessionBean/remote] and Local JNDI - [SlsSessionBean/local]

if - @Stateless(name="SlsSessionBean", mappedName="SlsSessionBeanGlobal")

Then Remote JNDI- [SlsSessionBeanGlobal] and Local JNDI - [SlsSessionBean/local]